# Loading a chinese encoding file in vim, conversion errors

Tags: vim, encoding, character-encoding, chinese

I can view http://hosting2.phor.net/~bolomi/ and save this to a file. In Chrome, I can view source and see the title of the page is 波羅蜜. If I open the saved file in vim to edit, I see question marks for those characters. Then if I `:set encoding=gb2312` I will see the first two characters and then question marks. If, instead, I do `:e ++enc=gb2312 %:p` I will see the middle character.

After the file is open (because I use MacVim and Fetch opens the file for me automatically) what is the correct workflow to edit this file?

Answer (score 1):

I found specifying `set encoding=cp936` for the troublesome `*.ahk` script solved my problem altogether.

Source: [用vim打开后中文乱码怎么办？ - doacker的回答 - 知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/22363620/answer/423443077)

Comment: Thank you. Obviously Zhihu is where I should have asked first!

Answer (score 0):

gb2312 only does simplified characters.

Firefox, Mozilla, and python2-chardet-2.0.1 all lie and say this is gb2312, but since it has traditional characters, the charset needed is gb18030.

So: if it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, smells like a duck, and tastes like a duck...  open the file with hexdump and read the codepage definition file.

Answer (score 0):

I have vim set to use UTF-8, as as far as I can see the characters correctly. Maybe try

```
set encoding=utf-8
```